# Show downloading progress bar only on one particular card in listview

Tags: flutter

I have implemented a listview.builder and i want to download a video file when pressed on the download icon and show the download progress bar only on that particular card.

Can't figure a way to do that.Any help would be great!!
I am getting the following when pressed on first card's download icon:

[image]

This is the code:

```
String downloadMessage = ' ';
  bool _isDownloading = false;

Widget checkid(int index){
    if(widget.data[index]["unit_id"].toString() == widget.unitid){
      return articles(index);
    }
  }

  Container articles(int index){
    
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20, left: 13.0, right: 22.0),
                  child: Row(
                    
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(widget.data[index]["video_size"]+" MB"),

                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.file_download), 
                            onPressed: () async {

                              _index = index;
                              bool exist = await db.checkdataid(widget.data[index]["data_video_id"]);
                              print(exist);
                              if(exist == false){
                                VideoDetails videoDetail = new VideoDetails(data_id: widget.data[index]["data_video_id"]);
                              await networkUtils.videodetail(url,body:videoDetail.toMap());
                              }
                              String videopath = await db.getvideopath();
                              videourl = baseurl + videopath;
                              print(videourl);

                              setState(() {
                                _isDownloading = !_isDownloading;
                              });

                              var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

                              Dio dio = Dio();
                              dio.download(
                                videourl, 
                                '${dir.path}/sample.ehb',
                                onReceiveProgress: (actualbytes , totalbytes){
                                  var percentage = actualbytes/totalbytes * 100;
                                  setState(() {
                                    downloadMessage = 'Downloading ${percentage.floor()} %';
                                  });
                                }
                              );
                            }
                          ),
                          Text(downloadMessage ?? '',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),)
                          
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 300,
                        child: Text(widget.data[index]["topic_name"],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                      ),
                      
                    ],
                                    
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[700],
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 110, 0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 200, 0),
                  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    color: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    ),
                  
                ),
                ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Text(" ",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 32,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text("Unit " + widget.unitno,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Text('',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 17),
              ),

            ],

          ),
          SizedBox(height: 40,),
          Container(
            // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 185,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white70,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(75.0),),
            ),
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 100, 0, 70),
                
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: widget.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                    return Container(
                      child: checkid(index),
                    );
                  }),
            
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: index == _index?  _isDownloading  ? Text(downloadMessage ?? '',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),)  : SizedBox() : SizedBox()


Try with this type brother

Comment: have a list of ints indicating the progress of the download. To display it in your listview do this. Text(list[index]==0?"":list[index].toString()); The "" displays an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to refactor the widget that you return inside the `articles` method to its own `Statefull` widget which has knowledege of its download or not, like so

```dart
class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  dynamic item;

  ListItem({
    this.index,
    this.item,
  });

  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
  bool _isDownloading = false;
  String downloadMessage = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              child: Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 20.0, bottom: 20, left: 13.0, right: 22.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(item["video_size"] + " MB"),
                          IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.file_download),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                _index = index;
                                bool exist = await db.checkdataid(
                                  item["data_video_id"]);
                                print(exist);
                                if (exist == false) {
                                  VideoDetails videoDetail = new VideoDetails(
                                      data_id: widget.data[index]
                                          ["data_video_id"]);
                                  await networkUtils.videodetail(url,
                                      body: videoDetail.toMap());
                                }
                                String videopath = await db.getvideopath();
                                videourl = baseurl + videopath;
                                print(videourl);

                                setState(() {
                                  _isDownloading = !_isDownloading;
                                });

                                var dir =
                                    await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

                                Dio dio = Dio();
                                dio.download(videourl, '${dir.path}/sample.ehb',
                                    onReceiveProgress:
                                        (actualbytes, totalbytes) {
                                  var percentage =
                                      actualbytes / totalbytes * 100;
                                  setState(() {
                                    downloadMessage =
                                        'Downloading ${percentage.floor()} %';
                                  });
                                });
                              }),
                          Text(
                            downloadMessage ?? '',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 300,
                        child: Text(
                          item["topic_name"],
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and when you render them inside the parent widget like so

```dart
Widget checkid(int index){
    if(widget.data[index]["unit_id"].toString() == widget.unitid){
      return articles(index);
    }
  }

  Widget articles(index) {
     return ListItem(
          index: index,
          item: widget.data[index]
     );

  }

}
```

now, each item has its own downloading state and will not interfere with the others